# How to use a EEPROM using Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3

I have done a raspberry pi code transfer a data and receive in my file, but i need use to EEPROM that i have not any experience about this.
if possible please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange. Hopefully, you have already read through some of the [documentation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help), and taken the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour). If you've not done that, please do so. I feel that your question is unclear, and this may prevent you from getting a good answer to your question. If English is an issue, you may find some help using the [Google Translate app](https://translate.google.com/).

Comment: EEPROM might not be the best solution; use it only when you absolutely need to.

Comment: @user96931 Yes I very much agree.  I was about to say the following: "If the OP is going to use the real time clock module DS3231 which includes a "free" EEPROM inside the module, then using the free EEPROM is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> I have binary/text data in a text file.
>
> How do I copy the data to an EEPROM?

***Answer***

I would recommend the 24C256 EEPROM module.  I once played with a similar through hole chip 25LC256 but the wiring and soldering by hand is quite messy.  For newbies, I would recommend the dirt cheap modules.

[image: at24c256]

You can google sample programs.  See YouTube in references below.  I once wrote one myself in Rpi python and found it tedious, but then learning what is going on inside the little chip is itself a joy.

***References***

[AliExpress AT24C256 24C256 I2C Interface EEPROM Memory Module 8P Chip Power Supply Indicator Pull Up Resistor Direct Jumper Setting US$2.54/5Pcs](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/5Pcs-AT24C256-24C256-I2C-Interface-EEPROM-Memory-Module-8P-Chip-Power-Supply-Indicator-Pull-Up-Resistor/32839377346.html?spm=a2g0w.10010108.1000016.1.1cb33ff5vdlRAI&isOrigTitle=true)

[MicroShip I2C-Compatible (2-Wire) Serial EEPROM 256‑Kbit (32,768 x 8) Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/AT24C256C-I2C-Compatible-Serial-EEPROM-256-Kbit-20006042A.pdf)

[Raspberry Pi I2C Python Initial Testing with I2C-Tools - 3,929 views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-R75DpqFrBE)

[Raspberry Pi Read/Write data to EEPROM through I2C - 28,482 views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LowtLMt-IMM)

Update 2019may11hkt1109

*FRAM Module*

The OP's question is on EEPROM.  However, if he is doing R&D, small memory size, money is no concern, I think he should consider FRAM.

[AliExpress WaveShare I2C FM24CLXX FRAM module - US$12](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/FM24CLXX-FRAM-Board-FM24-F-RAM-Serial-board-with-I2C-interface-FM24CL-on-board/32812054533.html?spm=a2g0w.search0104.3.8.610d2b9bePxK5J&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_9_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=de651ade-bf74-459c-9040-477a696cba50-1&algo_pvid=de651ade-bf74-459c-9040-477a696cba50)

[Ferroelectric RAM - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectric_RAM)

> Ferroelectric RAM (FeRAM, F-RAM or FRAM) is a random-access memory
>   similar in construction to DRAM but using a ferroelectric layer
>   instead of a dielectric layer to achieve non-volatility. FeRAM is one
>   of a growing number of alternative non-volatile random-access memory
>   technologies that offer the same functionality as flash memory.
>
> FeRAM's advantages over Flash include: lower power usage, faster write
>   performance and a much greater maximum read/write endurance (about
>   1010 to 1014 cycles). FeRAMs have data retention times of more than 10
>   years at +85 °C (up to many decades at lower temperatures). Market
>   disadvantages of FeRAM are much lower storage densities than flash
>   devices, storage capacity limitations and higher cost. Like DRAM,
>   FeRAM read process is destructive, necessitating a write-after-read
>   architecture.

Comment: Note that there are pin compatible, drop in FRAM alternatives that are both better and sometimes  cheaper.

Comment: @crasic Ah I very much agree with you.  One problem is that I am a poor hobbyist who cannot afford new but more expensive things.  The WaveShare FRAM module is many times more expensive than AT24xx EEPROM.  I think I should point out in my answer that if OP is working in industrial or college R&D rather than newbie Micky Mouse projects, then he should definitely try FRAM first, otherwise his workplace's reputation would be damaged, and losing face of course, ... :)

Comment: I use cypress  64Kb for EEPROM Replacement [FM24CL64B-GTR](https://www.digikey.com/short/pz0r05) It is $4 vs $0.40 for an EEPROM equivalent, but still not excessive in onesie-twosie situations. The access time improvement is almost 10000x (500ns vs 5ms) for a 10x difference in cost, that is quite some value

Comment: Yes, I agree that for onsie-twosie situations, FRAM is the way to go.  By the way, I am very surprised to learn that the performance is 1000x.  I think it is very likely that FRAM cost will drop very fast, and in 10 or 20 years, EEPROM would disappear and become an item in computing history museum.

Comment: One more zero 10000x (for write) ! And I agree completely. However, Microchip (which now bought atmel) general   policy is to not obsolete parts, so the vanilla 24c or some rev of it will be around as long as there are customers I suppose.

Comment: Oh my goodness, so I lost count after 3 zeros.  You do reminds me that I once owned a little cute, UV light lamp, which was used to erase PROM which has a transparent glass roof on top of the die.  In those days, life was easy, and I didn't need to count too many zeros for memory size.  I guess I lost my counting power then. :)